# Succint, interactive proof that $y^2 = x$ in $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$

Tags: group-theory

Let $p$ be a large prime, such that $(p = 3) \mod{4}$. Let $x$ be an element of $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ such that, for some $y \in \mathbb{Z}^*_p$, we have $y^2 = x$. It is a well-known result that $y = x^{\frac{p+1}{4}}$: $y$ can be computed from $x$ through a sequence of repeated squarings, which makes $y$ long to compute from $x$.

Now, consider the case where a **prover** wants to prove to a **verifier** that it computed $y$ from $x$ (both $x$ and $p$ are known to both). Trivially, the prover can send $y$ to the verifier, which can verify $y^2 = x$.

However, since $p$ is large, the approach above can be heavy from a communication point of view. So, I am wondering if some mechanism like the following exists:

- The verifier randomly selects a (small) challenge $c$, which it sends to the prover.
- From $c$ and $y$, the prover (quickly) generates a (small) proof $r$, which it sends back to the verifier.
- The verifier (quickly) verifies the correctness of $r$, establishing that the prover indeed computed $y$.

Here, by **small** I mean significantly smaller than $p$, $x$ or $y$. By **quickly** I mean significantly faster than the time required to compute $y$ from $x$.

Comment: You should quantify the largeness of $p$ because $\log p$ is already small!

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself! By smaller than $p$ I mean, significantly less than $\log_2 p$ bits. In a real-world scenario, I could envision $p$ being in the tens of thousands of bits, or more!

Comment: where are you getting that estimate? I don't know much about concrete security estimate in group-theoretic crypto, but my impression was that elliptic curve groups are are of size ~250 bits generally, not tens of thousands.

Comment: I am using this mechanism as a special kind of verifiable delay function whose deliberately large output can be leveraged as a proof of space mechanism.

Comment: @Matteo Monti: since you wrote _space_, I guess you are not satisfied by the obvious: challenger/verifier picks random $y\in[0,p/2)$, computes and keeps $h\gets H(y)$, computes $x\gets y^2\bmod p$, can forget $y$, sends $x$, can forget $x$; prover gets $x$, computes $y'\gets x^{(p+1)/4}\bmod p$, and $h'\gets H(\min(h',p-h'))$; verifier get $h'$ and checks $h'=h$.